# Force primary key on a view

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, view, primary-key

I have the schema below : [image]

 I tried to create a view and did everything to get `IDStore_CardStore` column `NOT NULL` in order to make it as the primary key in me EF entity but no success: 
My aim is to select everything in the table `StockCard` even if it dosen't exist in `StockCardStores` but i need to keep `IDStore_CardStore` not null and unique

```
SELECT  ISNULL(dbo.StockCardsStores.IDStore_CardStore, NEWID()) AS IDStore_CardStore ,
        NULLIF(dbo.StockCard.IDStockCardIndex, NEWID()) AS IDStockCardIndex ,
        dbo.Stores.StoreName ,
        dbo.StockCardsStores.IDPurchaseInvoice ,
        NULLIF(dbo.StockCard.Designation,'')
FROM    dbo.Stores
        INNER JOIN dbo.StockCardsStores ON dbo.Stores.IDStore = dbo.StockCardsStores.IDStore
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.StockCard ON dbo.StockCardsStores.IDStockCardIndex = dbo.StockCard.IDStockCardIndex
```

Is there any other workaround !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think IDStore_CardStore already can't be null, because it's primary key in StockCardStores table. Maybe the problem is that IDStore_CardStore could have duplicated values in your view, making imposible to be the Primary Key of the view.

I don't know your requirements, but uou can Fake a Primary key for your view making something like this in the query:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.StockCardsStores.IDStore_CardStore DESC) AS Id_PK, ISNULL(dbo.StockCardsStores.IDStore_CardStore, NEWID()) AS IDStore_CardStore ,
        NULLIF(dbo.StockCard.IDStockCardIndex, NEWID()) AS IDStockCardIndex ,
        dbo.Stores.StoreName ,
        dbo.StockCardsStores.IDPurchaseInvoice ,
        NULLIF(dbo.StockCard.Designation,'')
FROM    dbo.Stores
        INNER JOIN dbo.StockCardsStores ON dbo.Stores.IDStore = dbo.StockCardsStores.IDStore
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.StockCard ON dbo.StockCardsStores.IDStockCardIndex = dbo.StockCard.IDStockCardIndex
```

And then ID_PK can be the PK of he view in EF.

Comment: The problem is I coudnt make this query as a view !

Comment: Why? Whats the error that EF give you when you import the view into your EF model?

Comment: Oh sorry it's an error cause i missed to add an alias to NULLIF(dbo.StockCard.Designation,'')

Comment: the aim is not reached yet..EF entity needs a not null column to make it primary key by default but here Id_PK is still null